# Making a order list upon selecting elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am creating step by step order with HTML, CSS and JS/JQ. So far I've finished the step functionality with alot of help, and my next mission is to create a list of which elements that has been `.selected` with the proper `.name` and `.price` for that `li`-item, and later multiple all the selected item prices to one total price on the bottom of the order-list.

[I have made a JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/superladremi/qhhr46kj/) that also visualizes what I am trying to accomplish.

Is there a efficient way to do this? I have no idea of how I can possibly achieve this, so I'm asking someone out there to give me a head start or something that can I can hang on to.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the proper name and price for what you have so far, you simply need to have something like:

```
var allLikes = $('.selected');
```

...to get each item that has been selected.

What you can do is in each item, instead of what you currently have here:

```
<li class="bananas nomarking" data-id="one">
  Hamburger
  <span class="banana_price">€ 8</span>
</li>
```

Do this:

```
<li class="bananas nomarking" data-id="one">
  <span class="banana_name">Hamburgers</span>
  <span class="banana_price">€ 8</span>
</li>
```

Now, you can select the `banana_name` and the `banana_price` for each item in `allLikes`. If you loop through `allLikes` and select each one and add them to the `topay` divs that you already have, you should be all set.

Comment: Thank you. I meant to update my fiddle to give the name a value aswell, but it did not update. Is it appropriate to ask what you mean by "loop through allLikes?"

Comment: You can do a `forEach()` loop or the `map()` function in JS to go through every item in `allLikes` and for each of those items, take their individual `banana_name` and `banana_price`, make a `div` with those, and push it to the `topay` divs you already have set up.

Comment: Thank you for the further explanation. I will work on this :o)

Answer (score 0):

To get all selected items

1.addClass(".selected") for selected element.

2.get name and price from element.hasClass(".selected").

3.sum all the price values by using list.